# MySQL Composite Foreign Key Insert Failing

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, innodb, composite-key

I have 2 tables with a composite foreign key between the 2. When I try to insert a row into the child table, I get a restraint failure, even though the values exist in the parent table.

Here's a overview of the parent table:

```
CREATE TABLE `residual_reports` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `processor` enum('1','2','3') NOT NULL,
  `posting_date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `approved_on` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `posting_date_2` (`processor`,`posting_date`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

The child table has the foreign key to the processor and posting date columns:

```
CREATE TABLE `residual_data` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `mid` varchar(29) DEFAULT NULL,
  `processor` enum('1','2','3') NOT NULL,
  `posting_date` date NOT NULL,
  ......
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `residual_data_ibfk_1` (`processor`,`posting_date`),
  CONSTRAINT `residual_data_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`processor`, `posting_date`) REFERENCES `residual_reports` (`processor`, `posting_date`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I inserted a row into the residual_reports table with processor = 1, and posting_date = 2010-03-10.

When I try to insert into the residual_data table with processor = 1, and posting_date = 2010-03-10.

```
INSERT INTO `residual_data`(processor,posting_date) VALUES ('1','2010-03-10');
```

I get an:

[Err] 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`residual_data`, CONSTRAINT `residual_data_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`processor`, `posting_date`) REFERENCES `residual_reports` (`processor`, `posting_date`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Verified that the values definitely exist in the parent table, but still get foreign key restraint errors. Is there something I'm missing with a composite foreign key?

Comment: Ok, so it has to so with the ENUM data type. I switched it to a TINYINT, and it works fine. Anyone know of any documentation on foreign keys and ENUM type data that would support this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suspect the ENUM's, did you do something with them afterwards? Did you change values or so?

Comment: I think you're right on this. I switched the data type to a tinyint, and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me as-is. Is it possible that changes to `residual_reports` have not been committed yet?

Answer (score 0):

What Mysql version do you use? It seems that they have similar problems before with enum values 
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=24985

Comment: 5.1.41. Charset is latin1, and this isn't a primary key, so I don't think that bug applies. Not sure if this is a bug, or not. I cannot find reference to enum foreign keys in the documentation though.